# How do I make a inputFile field required?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am unable to make input file field required as like standard required in salesforce.
I am not using any javascript for this.
I have set Required Attribute to True. But the error occurring when I don't select a file is not user friendly. 
Can anyone help me out for this?

See [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l6gtAAA) for an example of the error message.

Comment: Can you confirm if you have tried using the required attribute for [apex:inputFile](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputFile.htm)? The error message that is displayed to the user when an inputFile is required may not be [that friendly](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l6gtAAA)

Comment: Yes exactly. I have used Required attribute. but the error message which is getting displayed is not that user friendly.

Comment: If you edit your question to explain this then we should be able to help out.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `required` attribute - Quoting the [official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputFile.htm)

> required  - Boolean   *A Boolean value that specifies whether this
>   inputField is a required field. If set to true, the user must specify
>   a value for this field. If not selected, this value defaults to false.
>   Note that if this input field displays a custom object name its value
>   can be set to nil and will not be required unless you set this
>   attribute to true. The same does not apply to standard object names,
>   which are always required regardless of this attribute.*

Comment: I already have used required Attribute. It is showing me an error if I don't choose any file.  Error is " Body: Validation Error: Value is Required". How to deal with error If I don't want it to display.